# In Jira, how to show a field with a sub-task's parent issue?

Tags: jira

In the Jira Issues view, how can a column be displayed to show the parent issue of the current row?  A hyperlink to the parent is included in the Summary column, but how can a freestanding column be configured to contain the parent?

Comment: I'm not sure that SO is the right place for a question about using Jira. Jira is project management tool and not programming language or IDE.

Comment: Actually, as the only way I know to achieve it is by code (see my answer), I think SO is a good place as any.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Script Runner plugin, you can create a **scripted field** which automatically includes a link to the parent issue. Then you can display this field in the issues table view.
Use the following code as the field's script:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager;

def burl = ComponentManager.getInstance().getApplicationProperties().getString("jira.baseurl")

return (issue.parent != null) ? "<a href=\""+ burl + "/browse/"+ issue.parentObject.key + "\">"+ issue.parentObject.key + "</a>" : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this - if you have ScriptRunner - is to create a Custom Script Field with this code:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue

return issue.getParentObject().getSummary()
```

Then you just add this field like any field to a JQL filter or screen & it will display the summary of the parent task.

I tried the answer above but was getting errors. Guessing the API's have changed since that was posted.